# PHP Remote MSSQL Connection

Tags: php, sql-server, remote-server

I'm trying to develop a solution for my company and my goal is to connect our web server (which is on php and there is a web site already running on it) to our CRM database ( which is on mssql and based on another server ). My first solution is to have a replica of this CRM database in web server and do synchronization on it daily or hourly because of security issues. But now I'm thinking about making a direct connection, do you think will that be possible and if it's possible what can be the security problems I may come across. Do anyone have an experience on this kind of problem?

Thanks

J

Answer (score 0):

Connecting to remote database will be slow, but at least your data will be consistent. If speed is not everything, I suggest this method. Migrating data can be painful.

You may want to create secure (SSL) connection between the servers. For detailed information please ask your system administrator.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer Ene actually, I am more worried about the security since our companies booking details and etc. is based in that database, do you think SSL would be enough for this?

Comment: Use VPN as well, it will be more secure. SSL is a must. The combination of this two should be enough. You should consult with your sytem administrator.

Answer (score 0):

doing the synchronization daily should be discouraged because you will lose real time data reliability.

If you are using PHP version 5.1, it still supports php-mssql connection thru php_mssql.dll, just be sure to enable it on your PHP.ini

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php  
$serverName = "ServerName"; /// use remote server name here
$uid = "sqlusername";   
$pwd = "sqlpassword";  
$databaseName = "DBName"; 

$connectionInfo = array( "UID"=>$uid,                            
                         "PWD"=>$pwd,                            
                         "Database"=>$databaseName); 

/* Connect using SQL Server Authentication. */  
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);  

$tsql = "SELECT id, FirstName, LastName, Email FROM tblContact";  

/* Execute the query. */  

$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $tsql);  

if ( $stmt )  
{  
     echo "Statement executed.<br>\n";  
}   
else   
{  
     echo "Error in statement execution.\n";  
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));  
}  

/* Iterate through the result set printing a row of data upon each iteration.*/  

while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_NUMERIC))  
{  
     echo "Col1: ".$row[0]."\n";  
     echo "Col2: ".$row[1]."\n";  
     echo "Col3: ".$row[2]."<br>\n";  
     echo "-----------------<br>\n";  
}  

/* Free statement and connection resources. */  
sqlsrv_free_stmt( $stmt);  
sqlsrv_close( $conn);  
?>
```